# How to handle one html element id for two or multiple javascript or jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on a MVC project ,there i have implemented an autocomplete text box search feature with the help of javascript and jquery.

The `<ul id="selectedValue" style="height:200px; width:18%;overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;"></ul>` HTML element tag is showing the list of the items by fetching the values from the Microsoft sql server database..

My autocomplete text box search is working perfectly fine..

Here is a piece of code of the index file of my MVC Autocomplete project.The itesm list values are fetching on the base of the  `id="selectedValue"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textbox;
var selectValue;

$(function () {
    textbox = $("#txtCountrty");
    selectValue = $('ul#selectedValue');

    textbox.on("input", function () {
        getAutoComplete(textbox.val());
    });
});
function getAutoComplete(countryName) {
    var uri = "Home/GetCountry";
    $.getJSON(uri, { countryName: countryName })
   .done(function (data) {
       selectValue.html("");
       var count = 0;
       $.each(data, function (key, item) {
           //$('<option>').text(item).appendTo('#selectedValue');
           var li = $('<li/>').addClass('ui-menu-item').attr('role', 'menuitem')
               .html("<a href='#' onclick=\"setText('" + item + "')\">" + item + "</a>")
               .appendTo(selectValue);

           count++;
       });
   });
}
function setText(text) {
    textbox.val(text);
    getAutoComplete(text);
}
```

```
 <div id="nav">
    <input type="text" id="txtCountrty"  />
    <div >
    <ul id="selectedValue" style="height:200px; width:18%;overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;"></ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Now here is a second Simple HTMl Javascript code in which i have implemented the auto scroll functionality by using the mouse movement.

The list is scrolling  on the base of the `id="list"`.

```js
var ly;

$(function() {
  $("#list").mousemove(function(e) {
      if (ly) {
        $("#list").scrollTop($("#list").scrollTop()+ly-e.clientY);
        ly = e.clientY;
      } else {
        ly = e.clientY;
      };
  });
  $("#list").mouseleave(function() {
    ly = null;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<ul id="list" style="height:200px; width:18%;overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
        <li>Henry Christensen</li>
        <li>Imelda Silva</li>
        <li>Marah Mueller</li>
        <li>Holly Fitzpatrick</li>
        <li>Lamar Flynn</li>
        <li>Jameson Davidson</li>
        <li>Harper Lynn</li>
        <li>Keith Woods</li>
        <li>Cally Dominguez</li>
        <li>Carter Gould</li>
        <li>Brenna Sutton</li>
        <li>Robert Vang</li>
        <li>Lane Shepard</li>
        <li>Ila Shepard</li>
        <li>Madaline Mccarthy</li>
        <li>Raya King</li>
        <li>Tara Schroeder</li>
        <li>Paloma Bryan</li>
        <li>Trevor Heath</li>
        <li>Raymond Vega</li>
        <li>Nyssa Mcleod</li>
        <li>Zachary Deleon</li>
        <li>Guy Morales</li>
        <li>Gannon Kline</li>
        <li>Clare Floyd</li>
      </ul>
</body>
```

Now i want to Implement the second code that is auto scroll with mouse movement into my Autocomplete search box MVC project.

when i uses the same id in two different functions .The autocomplete text box function work but the second function dose not run .

I am unable to understand how we can use the same html element id in two different java script functions or how we can run the second function after the completion of the first function.I have made the function call for the 2nd funtion on the end of the first function but it dose not work.

or any other solution or thoughts will be very appreciated.
Bundle of thanks for you and your great time.

Comment: 'I don't understand the issue here???

Comment: I don't understand the problem either. Surely you just change the jQuery selector for your autoscroll function from `$("#list")` to `$("#selectedValue")`?

Comment: @Moob : Dear friend you even did not bother to read my post. There is two different code and i want to integrate them with each other.i want to implement the autoscroll code which is in Snippet to the above code that is with out snippet.